# Rendering float divs from html to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, html-to-pdf

Is there any way to generate PDF from html with floating divs (I can event use fixed width and height values for divs), margins and padding in Python? Does anybody know python libs which work correctly with this css property or may be system tools? Any info will be helpfull.

I have tried wkhtmltopdf. Pisa excluded immediately...

Answer (score 1):

not python, but you could try http://phantomjs.org/ simple js to generate a page, then  just call `.render` to generate a pdf

Comment: It will be an image, but from http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html "Beside PNG format, PhantomJS supports JPEG, GIF, and PDF."

(I realise that's probably not quite what you want)